# Specify Icon for Windows Application using Visual Studio 2008 - Beginner's Question

Tags: visual-studio-2008, icons, setup-project, setup-deployment

I am building a Windows Application using Visual Studio 2008. For the forms (2 of them), I have specified icons.

Now, I build the Setup by adding Setup and Deployment Project to my solution. In properties of the Setup and Deployment Project, I specify the Icon.

Then I do the following

1. I create a Shortcut to the Primary Output of my Application (the executable). Link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syyw4edd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).
2. I cut/paste it to the User's Desktop under the File System on Target's Machine. Link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sat42980%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).
3. To the properties, I add the Icon

Now, in the Add/Remove Programs, I have the icon. 
In the Desktop, I have the icon. But the actual executable file still comes with the standard exe icon.

How can I have my icon for the actual executable also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your project's properties to the Application page.

Under the Resources frame you can change the Icon from the default icon to an icon in your resources or you can browse for an icon on your machine.

[image: Project Properties - Application page]

Comment: Thanks a lot! As an aside, how do you get to know these things...? :-)

Comment: @Kanini: I keep banging my head against it until something sinks in ;)  Seriously, the longer you work with the tools, the more familiar you will become with them.  It helps that I get paid to write code which means I also get paid to learn as I go along.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2008 menu, go to "Project > [Project_Name] Properties... > Application". In the "Resources" groupbox, select the icon in the field below "Icon and manifest". Compile.